# Linq содержит ли последовательность все елементы другой последовательности

Tags: c#, linq

Возможно, такой вопрос проскакивал, но не нашёл такого.
 Как мне с помощью Linq проверить содержит ли какая-либо коллекция все елементы другой коллекции? Размер коллекции должен игнорироваться.

Comment: У массивов есть метод расширения Except которая вычисляется разницу между 1 и 2 коллекцией. Соответственно в качестве первого массива берешь тот, который содержит меньше элементов. В результате если все элементы меньшего массива будут в большем, то результат выполнения вернёт 0 элементом.

Comment: Единственное для сравнения массивов из своих классов нужно будет переопределить их Equals и GetHashCode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если речь идет о массивах или иных коллекциях с поддержкой `Contains`, то определить есть ли хотя бы 1 элемент в первой коллекции, который был бы и во второй

```
var first = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var second = new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

if (first.Any(x => second.Contains(x)))
    Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(second)} contains some elements from {nameof(first)}");
```

Вывод

```
second contains some elements from first
```

Если нужно определить, все ли элементы второй коллекции в первой, то

```
var first = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var second = new[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 };

if (second.All(x => first.Contains(x)))
    Console.WriteLine($"All elements from {nameof(second)} contains in {nameof(first)}");
```

Вывод

```
All elements from second contains in first
```